# How can I run the Ruby on Rails console in production without executing Spring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, console, server

Every time I run `rails console` on my production server, `spring` starts and I forget to stop it.. and some of my RAM goes away...

Is there some way to prevent Spring from starting in a production environment?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found it. You need to set the environment variable `DISABLE_SPRING` to true when executing the console, like this:

```
DISABLE_SPRING=true rails console
```

That way the Spring server will not load.

To do this automatically, you can export this variable in your `.bashrc`, `.tcshrc`, `.zshrc` appending this code to it:

```
export DISABLE_SPRING=true
```

and then loading it, in my case (I'm using zsh):

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Reference:

https://github.com/rails/spring

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-export-command/

Comment: That solved a problem for me.  Because of the way the server was configured, I had to add 'production' in order to run the console in production. 

```DISABLE_SPRING=true rails console```

Comment: UGg. Meant to say ```DISABLE_SPRING=true rails console production ```

Answer (score 2):

Put `spring`in your testing group in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem "spring", group: :test
```

or

```
group :test do
 gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: This works but spring will not load on my development machine and this is not desirable. Thanks for your answer.